# macOS SwiftUI: How do I constrain text to be the width of an image in a VStack?

Tags: macos, swiftui

The following code generates this layout. I’d like for the text to wrap at the width of the image, and take up as much vertical space as it needs. The resulting window should not be resizable (so I’m using `.windowResizability(.contentSize)` on the `Window` scene).

I’ve tried various combinations of `.fixedSize()` and `.layoutPriority()`, but they seem to have no effect. Back in the UIKit days I'd set the horizontal content compression resistance priority lower.

I’m hoping to do this without resorting to alignment guides or `GeometryReader`. I feel like it should be possible to have text wrap in this scenario.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode preview showing an image of a keyboard with lorem ipsum text below; the text isn’t wrapping and is wider than the image.]

```swift
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Image("keyboard")
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                .font(.system(size: 24.0))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
        .fixedSize()
    }
}

#Preview
{
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the image size and apply it to the text in 4 simple steps:

```
// 1️⃣ Define a ChildSizeReader to bind the size later:

struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    let content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        content()
            .background(GeometryReader { Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: $0.size) })
            .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { size = $0 }
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGSize.zero
    static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) { }
}

// ---

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imageSize = CGSize.zero // 2️⃣ Define a simple state to keep the size 

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ChildSizeReader(size: $imageSize) { // 3️⃣ Surround the child you want (the image in your case) in that:
                Image("keyboard") //  You need the size of this view
            }

            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                .font(.system(size: 24.0))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(maxWidth: imageSize.width) // 4️⃣ Limit the size like this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual size of the image then I would suggest, the best solution is to set this as the `maxWidth` on the `VStack` and allow the image to be scaled to fit when the window is smaller.

For testing, I used a screenshot of your image and scaled it to have a width of 500:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("keyboard")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
            .font(.system(size: 24.0))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: 500)
}
```

If you don't know the actual size of the image then you could show the text in an overlay instead. This is a sure way to get the correct width, but the problem is that the offset-overlay does not get included in the layout so it will overlap any content that follows. A hidden placeholder can be used to reserve space for one line, at least:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("keyboard")
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .offset(y: proxy.size.height + 10) // + spacing
                }
            }
        Text("One line placeholder").hidden()
    }
    .font(.system(size: 24.0))
}
```

If in fact you know that the text will always wrap to, say, 3 lines, then you could add bottom padding to the image to reserve space. Then, the overlay could use `alignment: bottom` and you wouldn't need either the `GeometryReader` or the offset.

Comment: That text resizing is a bug I ran into earlier. In this case, I'm making the entire window fixed to the smallest size that will contain the text and the image (using `.windowResizability(.contentSize)`).

Adding an HStack and colors on either side result in large margins left and right.

Comment: Sorry, one more edit with what I think is a better solution. I scrapped the original suggestion (with the HStack) because it gives undesirable margins.